# Why is my static IP configuration not working in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, ip

I installed a fresh version of Minimal CentOS 7.

I can `ping google.com` when it is set to `dhcp`.

When I run `nmcli -p dev` I receive:

```
enp2s0f0 ethernet connected enp2s0f0
lo       loopback unmanaged --
```

Based on the many articles I've now been exposed to, I know I need to edit this file:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0f0`

This is my resulting file:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp2s0f0
UUID=[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
DEVICE=enp2s0f0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.90.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.169.90.254
```

I've also edited my `/etc/resolv.conf` file to include:

```
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

After all of the above is completed, I run `systemctl restart network`.

But when I run `ping google.com`, it takes a few moments (about 20 seconds) and eventually returns `ping: google.com: Name or service not known`

After I run `nmcli -p dev` again, I see the same results as before.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `BOOTPROTO` is what was in the file before I ever edited it, and is also the property mentioned in all the "Set Static IP on CentOS7" articles I've read. Anyway, I tried `BOOTPROTOCOL=none` and `BOOTPROTO=none` and both are not working.

Comment: `192.168.90.1` is probably not right; very often .1 is used for the router. (There is no requirement that it is, but that's just the way most everyone does it, absent special requirements). Unless your router (gateway) really is .254.

Comment: I have tried alternatives. How can I determine the "right" value to use for the gateway?

Comment: I see now that I was going about this the wrong way and have to configure my IP address based on the existing value for `NETMASK`. Therefore, once I determined it as `10.2.0.1`, I had to set my `IPADDR` as `10.2.0.X` where `X` is a new value.

Comment: the right values are whatever is configured in your router. DHCP let's the router manage it all for you, static you have to take over. The netmask, network, gateway, DNS, will be the same as DHCP gave you. The address you have to pick yourself so it's (a) on the network, (b) unique

Comment: Depending on what you want a static IP for, you may find configuring a DHCP reservation in your router much easier.

Comment: I come from being a BSD admin. But the results you provide above *strongly* indicate that your system is *attempting* a DHCP setup. Even tho you're attempting a STATIC one.

Comment: Put the settings back to the way they were when you were able to ping google. Then attempt to `traceroute` google. This will give you a *strong* indication as to what your gateway is (first hop).

Answer (score 1):

if every configuration is ok type this command

```
nmcli connection up ethx    # or ensXX
```

where `ethx` (or `ensXX`) is your adapter's name

Comment: Yes. This worked like a charm. Does anybody know why systemctl restart is not enough.